# Kendo DropDownList Is Not Refreshing Properly

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-dropdown

I have a grid and dropdown list. Items of dropdownlist should change depends on which row I have selected in grid. It's working fine. But the problem is when I select another row, it's showing data from previous row. It's not refreshing properly.

For example:

I have two email list for site 1 (leo, chris, pablo) and 2 (mark, steve, bill).

When I select site 1 in grid (leo, chris, pablo) is loading into dropdown. When I select site 2 it's loading (mark, steve, bill) but displaying (leo) which is incorrect.

```js
function filterSiteDemoEmail(e) {
        var grid = $('#gridSiteDemo').data('kendoGrid');
        var currentDataItem = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
        return {
            ip_cmcode: currentDataItem.customerCode,
            ip_siteno: currentDataItem.siteNumber
        }
    }

function onGridSiteDemoRowSelection(e) {

        var grid = e.sender;
        var currentDataItem = grid.dataItem(this.select());
        if (currentDataItem != null) {
            $('#siteDemoEmailDropDownList').data('kendoDropDownList').dataSource.read();   
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                        @(Html.Kendo().Grid<ServicePROWeb.Controllers.GridController.SiteDemo>()
                            .Name("gridSiteDemo")
                            .Columns(columns =>
                            {
                                columns.Bound(p => p.customerCode).Title("Customer");
                                columns.Bound(p => p.siteNumber).Title("Site");
                            })
                            .Selectable()                            
                            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                            .Ajax()                            
                            .Read(read => read.Action("LoadCustomerSiteDemo", "Grid")))
                            .Events(events => events.Change("onGridSiteDemoRowSelection"))
                        )
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                        @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                            .Name("siteDemoEmailDropDownList")
                            .DataTextField("email")
                            .DataValueField("email")
                            .DataSource(source =>
                            {
                                source.Read(read =>
                                {
                                    read.Action("GetSiteDemoEmail", "Grid").Data("filterSiteDemoEmail"); //Set the Action and Controller name
                                })
                                .ServerFiltering(true); //If true the DataSource will not filter the data on the client.
                            })
                            .AutoBind(false)
                            .SelectedIndex(0)
                            .HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "width: 100%" })
                        )
                    </div>
                </div>
```

```
public class SiteDemo
    {
        public decimal customerCode { get; set; }
        public int siteNumber { get; set; }
    }

    public class SiteDemoEmail
    {
        public string email { get; set; }

    }

    public ActionResult LoadCustomerSiteDemo([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        List<SiteDemo> siteDemoList = new List<SiteDemo>();

        SiteDemo sd = new SiteDemo();
        sd.customerCode = 1;
        sd.siteNumber = 1;
        siteDemoList.Add(sd);

        sd = new SiteDemo();
        sd.customerCode = 1;
        sd.siteNumber = 2;
        siteDemoList.Add(sd);

        var jsonResult = Json(siteDemoList.ToDataSourceResult(request));
        jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
        jsonResult.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;

        return jsonResult;
    }

    public JsonResult GetSiteDemoEmail(decimal ip_cmcode, int ip_siteno)
    {
        CustomerRepository cr = new CustomerRepository();

        List<SiteDemoEmail> SiteDemoEmailList = new List<SiteDemoEmail>();

        if (ip_siteno == 1)
        {
            SiteDemoEmail sde = new SiteDemoEmail();
            sde.email = "leo@gmail.com";
            SiteDemoEmailList.Add(sde);

            sde = new SiteDemoEmail();
            sde.email = "chris@gmail.com";
            SiteDemoEmailList.Add(sde);

            sde = new SiteDemoEmail();
            sde.email = "pablo@gmail.com";
            SiteDemoEmailList.Add(sde);
        }
        else
        {
            SiteDemoEmail sde = new SiteDemoEmail();
            sde.email = "mark@gmail.com";
            SiteDemoEmailList.Add(sde);

            sde = new SiteDemoEmail();
            sde.email = "steve@gmail.com";
            SiteDemoEmailList.Add(sde);

            sde = new SiteDemoEmail();
            sde.email = "bill@gmail.com";
            SiteDemoEmailList.Add(sde);
        }

        return Json(SiteDemoEmailList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: I know for grids you normally refresh after a ds read. Does it work for the drop downs too?  $('#siteDemoEmailDropDownList').data('kendoDropDownList').refresh();

Comment: @RossBush: Thanks. I tried with refresh. It does not work either.

Comment: What if you force a select to item 0 on the drop downs data bound event to refresh the selection.  ('#siteDemoEmailDropDownList').data('kendoDropDownList').select(0);

Comment: @RossBush: Just tried. Nope. It does not work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing this line in onGridSiteDemoRowSelection handler:

```js
$('#siteDemoEmailDropDownList').data('kendoDropDownList').dataSource.read();
```

With

```js
var ddl = $('#siteDemoEmailDropDownList').data('kendoDropDownList');
ddl.dataSource.read()
ddl.select(0);
```

Seems to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This should do your job without selecting the first element.
Just set your ajax call to Post in order to prevent the ajax caching which works as default in the kendo dropdownlinst

```
.DataSource(source =>
 {
           source.Read(read =>
                   {
                           read.Action("ActionMethod", "Controller").Type(HttpVerbs.Post);
                    });
})
```

For more information you could check on this: https://www.telerik.com/forums/prevent-ajax-caching-on-read